# Sorting by a comma separated list, treating as integer

Tags: mysql, sorting

I have a query that gets a sort order through a group concat. It returns the sorting order in a comma separated list that has everything perfectly set. Ordering by the comma separated list ALMOST works perfectly. However it treats each set of data in the comma separated list as if it were a char.

That means when sorting it would go like this:

```
1,0
10,0
11,0
12,0
13,0
14,0
15,0
16,0
17,0
18,0
19,0
2,0
21,0
3,0
4,0
5,0
6,0
7,0
8,0
9,0
```

Rather than the correct order:

```
1,0
2,0
3,0
4,0
5,0
6,0
7,0
8,0
9,0
10,0
11,0
...    
20,0
21,0
```

How do I force mysql to treat these as integers? It would need to sort things correctly for when there are multiple values that are very similar. For example:

```
0,0
0,1
0,2
1,0
2,0
2,1
3,5
4,2
etc
```

The first value always sets the first position, then the second value the next position and so on.

The list can vary between 1 single value and 2-3 or more... but it is always filled with numbers. I've looked at substring_index, temporary tables, casting.. etc. Nothing seems to be working. Its weird because otherwise mySQL can sort just fine.

Comment: Do you really need GROUP_CONCAT ?

Comment: Yes. Otherwise a ton of rows will be returned redundantly.

Comment: And there are always (no more than) two values?

Comment: There could be only one, but there could also be dozens. One or two would be normal, but 3 would not be uncommon. There probably wouldn't be more than 3, but it should support more than 3.

Comment: I'd go for the 'ton of rows' option. But if you post up an sqlfiddle illustrating the problem in its simplest terms, I expect someone will post up a solution contradicting my advice